# get current SVG stroke value using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I want to get the current 'stroke' value for a particular svg element. This isn't a problem if the value has been set via javascript previously but when it is set by a class I don't seem to be able to get a return value using the following scripts...

```
el.getAttribute('stroke') //returns 'null'

el.setAttribute('stroke','red') // the stroke is visibly changed to 'red'

el.getAttribute('stroke') //returns 'red'
```

So how do I go about getting the current value when it is set via a style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

stroke is a CSS property so if you want to see what an element's stroke is no matter how it's been set then this should do it...

```
var stroke = window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue("stroke");
```